# Using FOR XML PATH to output Multiple Sibling Elements

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, for-xml-path, select-for-xml

From the database, I'm trying to generate an XML that looks like the following, for each row in the query result:

```
<Message>
<Header>
  <MessageName>MyMessage</MessageName>
  <TimeStamp>2017-03-31T14:32:48</TimeStamp>
  <TrackingNum>1</TrackingNum>
</Header>
<Body>
  <Activity>
    <GUID>SomeGUID</GUID>
    <OrderNum>3242432<OrderNum/>
    <OrderDate>20160331143248</OrderDate>
  </Activity>
</Body>
</Message>
```

The query I have looks like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT DISTINCT top 20
        [GUID],
        OrderNum,
        OrderDate,
    FROM TableA 
    For XML PATH('Activity'), Type
            ) as Body 
    For XML path('Message'),  TYPE
```

This query outputs all rows enclosed within  `<Message><Body>` tag, just one cell with the XML of everything. I don't know where to include the info for the `<Header>` part.

The query above produces the following, which is incorrect/incomplete:

```
 <Message>
    <Body>
        <Activity>
            <GUID>sdlksdkljsdkl</GUID>
            <OrderNum>23423423</OrderNum>
            <OrderDate>20160431143248</OrderDate>
        </Activity>   
        <Activity>
            <GUID>sdfsdfsw4erw</GUID>
            <OrderNum>45560900</OrderNum>
            <OrderDate>20160531143248</OrderDate>
        </Activity>   
        <Activity>
            <GUID>retertertwew</GUID>
            <OrderNum>873409384</OrderNum>
            <OrderDate>20160631143248</OrderDate>
        </Activity>   
    </Body>
</Message>
```

How do we get the Header Part appended before the `<Body>` tag, while splitting the output into multiple rows? Thank you for any help.

EDIT:
Mock data for the `Body/Activity` element :

```
 GUID       OrderNum           OrderDate      
 AAAA       1000               2017-04-13 12:00
 BBBB       2000               2017-04-13 12:00
 CCCC       3000               2017-04-13 12:00
```

I'm trying to get each row in their own xml as in the first XML block above.

Comment: Please create mock data for us so we can create the same table as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the Header as an *XML-typed column*:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([GUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,OrderNum BIGINT, OrderDate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(NEWID(),1111111,{ts'2001-01-01 01:00:00'})
                      ,(NEWID(),2222222,{ts'2002-02-02 02:00:00'})
                      ,(NEWID(),3333333,{ts'2003-03-03 03:00:00'});

SELECT 
   (
    SELECT 'SomeMessageName' AS MessageName
          ,GETDATE() AS [TimeStamp]
          ,1 AS TraxingNum
    FOR XML PATH('Header'),TYPE 
   )
  ,(
    SELECT DISTINCT top 20
        [GUID],
        OrderNum,
        OrderDate
    FROM @tbl AS TableA 
    For XML PATH('Activity'), Type
   ) as Body 
For XML path('Message'),TYPE;
```

The result

```
<Message>
  <Header>
    <MessageName>SomeMessageName</MessageName>
    <TimeStamp>2017-04-13T10:20:09</TimeStamp>
    <TraxingNum>1</TraxingNum>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Activity>
      <GUID>79DE31D2-4727-4880-BB11-72564AE707B0</GUID>
      <OrderNum>3333333</OrderNum>
      <OrderDate>2003-03-03T03:00:00</OrderDate>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <GUID>A9410295-5C78-4EC8-A904-8CB1D10563CF</GUID>
      <OrderNum>2222222</OrderNum>
      <OrderDate>2002-02-02T02:00:00</OrderDate>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <GUID>3192B87D-7C1A-4B95-A477-E10D2FC2845F</GUID>
      <OrderNum>1111111</OrderNum>
      <OrderDate>2001-01-01T01:00:00</OrderDate>
    </Activity>
  </Body>
</Message>
```

### Hints

- In your example your dates are like this `20160531143248`. You should use ISO8601 *within* XML always. Otherwise you will get extra pain, when you try to read this.
- Using `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` is - uhm - at least dangerous... (you see, that the order in my result is not the expected order?)

### UPDATE

According to your comments I think you are searching for one of these (test them with my *mock-up* table from above):

```
SELECT 
      'SomeMessageName' AS [Header/MessageName]
      ,GETDATE() AS [Header/TimeStamp]
      ,1 AS [Header/TraxingNum]
      ,[GUID] AS [Body/GUID]
      ,OrderNum AS [Body/OrderNum]
      ,OrderDate AS [Body/OrderDate]
FROM @tbl AS TableA
FOR XML PATH('Message'),TYPE;

SELECT 
      (SELECT
      'SomeMessageName' AS [Header/MessageName]
      ,GETDATE() AS [Header/TimeStamp]
      ,1 AS [Header/TraxingNum]
      ,[GUID] AS [Body/GUID]
      ,OrderNum AS [Body/OrderNum]
      ,OrderDate AS [Body/OrderDate]
      FOR XML PATH('Message'),TYPE)
FROM @tbl AS TableA;
```

Comment: Point Taken re TOP without ORDER BY; I was typing the question in a hurry, and it is my mistake that I forgot; Sorry. Agree with you  re-the date format as well.

Comment: THank you. I'm trying to get only one `Activity` element within the `Body` element, and the next one should be in the next row. How do I force SQL Server to break it down to different rows? I hope this make sense.